# How can I rbind with missing dataframes?

Tags: r, sqldf, rbind

I'm doing campaign finance data and am searching for employees of x corporation who have donated x amount of money between 1989 and 2010. Using sqldf I was able to parse out this information. The data is >4gb where my ram is <2gb so I have broken the data into about 100mb spreadsheets and have 40 that I load to get this information. Some have contributors from corporation x, some do not.

Does anyone know how to make a 'catchers mitt' for the files? This 'catchers mitt' will identify these relevant files and bind the rows.

I'm attaching my code in case anyone would also like to make general improvements?

Thanks for your help

```
#Individual Donors for Retail Sales Companies 1990-2010

#load file

    indiv00.1<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv00.1.csv")
    indiv00.2<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv00.2.csv")
    indiv00.3<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv00.3.csv")
    indiv00.4<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv00.4.csv")
    indiv00.5<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv02.1.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name1<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.1' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")   
    name2<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.2' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name3<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.3' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name4<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.4' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name5<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.5' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check

#merge data

    na1<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name1 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na2<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name2 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na3<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name3 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na4<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name4 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na5<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name5 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na1", mode="global.env"))save(na1,file="na1.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na2", mode="global.env"))save(na2,file="na2.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na3", mode="global.env"))save(na3,file="na3.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na4", mode="global.env"))save(na4,file="na4.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na5", mode="global.env"))save(na5,file="na5.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#load file

    indiv00.6<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv02.2.csv")
    indiv00.7<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv02.3.csv")
    indiv00.8<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.1.csv")
    indiv00.9<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.2.csv")
    indiv00.10<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.3.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name    

    name6<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.6' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name7<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.7' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name8<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.8' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name9<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.9' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name10<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.10' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")   

#check

#merge data

    na6<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name6 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na7<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name7 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na8<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name8 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na9<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name9 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na10<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name10 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na6", mode="global.env"))save(na6,file="na6.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na7", mode="global.env"))save(na7,file="na7.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na8", mode="global.env"))save(na8,file="na8.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na9", mode="global.env"))save(na9,file="na9.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na10", mode="global.env"))save(na10,file="na10.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#load file

    indiv00.11<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.4.csv")
    indiv00.12<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.5.csv")
    indiv00.13<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv04.6.csv")
    indiv00.14<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv06.1.csv")
    indiv00.15<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv06.2.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name11<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.11' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '") 
    name12<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.12' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name13<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.13' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name14<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.14' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name15<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.15' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#merge

    na11<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name11 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na12<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name12 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na13<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name13 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na14<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name14 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na15<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name15 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na11", mode="global.env"))save(na11,file="na11.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na12", mode="global.env"))save(na12,file="na12.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na13", mode="global.env"))save(na13,file="na13.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na14", mode="global.env"))save(na14,file="na14.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na15", mode="global.env"))save(na15,file="na15.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check  

#load file

    indiv00.16<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv06.3.csv")
    indiv00.17<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv06.4.csv")
    indiv00.18<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv06.5.csv")
    indiv00.19<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.1.csv")
    indiv00.20<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.2.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name16<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.16' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name17<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.17' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name18<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.18' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name19<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.19' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name20<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.20' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check 

#merge

    na16<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name16 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na17<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name17 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na18<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name18 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na19<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name19 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na20<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name20 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na16", mode="global.env"))save(na16,file="na16.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na17", mode="global.env"))save(na17,file="na17.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na18", mode="global.env"))save(na18,file="na18.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na19", mode="global.env"))save(na19,file="na19.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na20", mode="global.env"))save(na20,file="na20.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check  

#load file

    indiv00.21<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.3.csv")
    indiv00.22<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.4.csv")
    indiv00.23<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.5.csv")
    indiv00.24<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.6.csv")
    indiv00.25<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.7.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name21<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.21' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '") 
    name22<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.22' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name23<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.23' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name24<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.24' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name25<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.25' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check  

#merge

    na21<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name21 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na22<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name22 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na23<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name23 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na24<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name24 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na25<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name25 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na21", mode="global.env"))save(na21,file="na21.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na22", mode="global.env"))save(na22,file="na22.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na23", mode="global.env"))save(na23,file="na23.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na24", mode="global.env"))save(na24,file="na24.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na25", mode="global.env"))save(na25,file="na25.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#Load file

    indiv00.26<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.8.csv")
    indiv00.27<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv08.9.csv")
    indiv00.28<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv10.1.csv")
    indiv00.29<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv10.2.csv")
    indiv00.30<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv10.3.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name26<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.26' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '") 
    name27<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.27' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name28<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.28' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name29<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.29' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name30<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.30' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check

#merge

    na26<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name26 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na27<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name27 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na28<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name28 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na29<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name29 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na30<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name30 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na26", mode="global.env"))save(na26,file="na26.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na27", mode="global.env"))save(na27,file="na27.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na28", mode="global.env"))save(na28,file="na28.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na29", mode="global.env"))save(na29,file="na29.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na30", mode="global.env"))save(na30,file="na30.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#load file

    indiv00.31<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv10.4.csv")
    indiv00.32<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv10.5.csv")
    indiv00.33<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv96.csv")
    indiv00.34<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv96.2.csv")
    indiv00.35<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv98.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

    name31<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.31' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '") 
    name32<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.32' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name33<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.33' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name34<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.34' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name35<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.35' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check

#merge

    na31<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name31 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na32<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name32 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na33<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name33 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na34<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name34 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na35<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name35 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na31", mode="global.env"))save(na31,file="na31.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na32", mode="global.env"))save(na32,file="na32.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na33", mode="global.env"))save(na33,file="na33.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na34", mode="global.env"))save(na34,file="na34.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na35", mode="global.env"))save(na35,file="na35.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#load file

    indiv00.36<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv98.2.csv")
    indiv00.37<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indiv98.3.csv")
    indiv00.38<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indivs90.csv")
    indiv00.39<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indivs92.csv")
    indiv00.40<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\indivs\\indivs94.csv")

#check

#library

    library(sqldf)

#search for name

#check
    name36<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.36' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name37<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.37' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name38<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.38' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name39<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.39' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")
    name40<-sqldf("select * from 'indiv00.40' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")

#check

#merge

    na36<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name36 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na37<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name37 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na38<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name38 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

    na39<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name39 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle")

    na40<-sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name40 group by 
    ContribID,Cycle") 

#check

#save data

    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data")

    if(!exists("na36", mode="global.env"))save(na36,file="na36.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na37", mode="global.env"))save(na37,file="na37.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na38", mode="global.env"))save(na38,file="na38.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na39", mode="global.env"))save(na39,file="na39.Rdata")
    if(!exists("na40", mode="global.env"))save(na40,file="na40.Rdata")

#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check

#load file

    a1<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na1.Rdata")
    a2<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na2.Rdata")
    a3<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na3.Rdata")
    a4<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na4.Rdata")
    a5<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na5.Rdata")
    a6<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na6.Rdata")
    a7<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na7.Rdata")
    a8<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na8.Rdata")
    a9<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na9.Rdata")
    a10<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na10.Rdata")
    a11<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na11.Rdata")
    a12<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na12.Rdata")
    a13<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na13.Rdata")
    a14<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na14.Rdata")
    a15<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na15.Rdata")
    a16<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na16.Rdata")
    a17<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na17.Rdata")
    a18<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na18.Rdata")
    a19<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na19.Rdata")
    a20<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na20.Rdata")
    a21<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na21.Rdata")
    a22<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na22.Rdata")
    a23<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na23.Rdata")
    a24<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na24.Rdata")
    a25<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na25.Rdata")
    a26<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na26.Rdata")
    a27<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na27.Rdata")
    a28<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na28.Rdata")
    a29<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na29.Rdata")
    a30<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na30.Rdata")
    a31<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na31.Rdata")
    a32<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na32.Rdata")
    a33<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na33.Rdata")
    a34<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na34.Rdata")
    a35<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na35.Rdata")
    a36<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na36.Rdata")
    a37<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na37.Rdata")
    a38<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na38.Rdata")
    a39<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na39.Rdata")
    a40<-load("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\na40.Rdata")

#global environment

    b<-c(ls())
    B<-paste("n",b)
    paste(B,",")    

#clean in text editor

#check      #check      #check      #check      #check
#check      #check      #check      #check      #check
#check      #check      #check      #check      #check

#Row bind


    name<-rbind(

















    )


#write table
#library
    library(XML)
    setwd("C:\\Users\\tbrown11\\Desktop\\Data\\Retail")
#writing table to csv
    out_file <- file("Walmart.csv", open="a")
    write.table(name, file=out_file, sep=",", dec=".", quote=FALSE, 
    col.names=NA, row.names=TRUE)
    close(out_file)
#check

#clean house

    rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())

#check
```

Comment: Note `read.csv.sql` in sqldf which reads a file and applies an sql statement all in one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing the same thing over and over again you should think about using a loop of some kind. 
Implicit loops in R like lapply

A list of all the relevant files:

```
myFunction = function(f)
{ 
  require(sqldf)
  ##Better to use require, since if the library is already loaded it
  ##won't try to load it again
  indiv <- read.csv(f)
  name <- sqldf("select * from 'indiv' where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '")   
  na <- sqldf("select Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
               Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
               RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp from name group by 
               ContribID,Cycle") 

  if(!exists("na", mode="global.env"))save(na,file="na.Rdata")
  rm(list = ls(), envir = globalenv())
}

setwd("~/relevant_directories")
files = list.files()
pre.results = lapply(files, myFunction)
results = do.call(rbind, pre.results)

##Do whatever you want with your results then!
```

You would have to tweak the myFunction code to not save over the same na.Rdata code each time it is called, but that shouldn't be too hard. Perhaps pass a counter to the function and paste the counter to the file name

If your data file is too big to load into memory there are R packages that can help with this. Take a look at the ff package which has plenty of functions for accessing data files on the hard disk without having to load them into memory.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have heaps of repetition of `read.csv`, `sql('select * from ...')` etc - I think you can turn this into a loop. On each iteration of the loop you load a csv file, perform the query, and `rbind` the results.

Also, your query is currently in two steps -- `SELECT * .. where Orgname like '%Wal-Mart..'`, and then you select various columns from that. You can combine these into one query (I think!):

```
library(sqldf)

# make a vector of all your files:
# indiv00.{1--4}, invid02.{1,2,3}, indiv04.{1--6}, indiv06.{1--5},
# indiv08.{1--9}, indiv10.{1--5}, indiv96, indiv96.2, indiv98, indiv98.{2,3},
# indivs{90,92,94}
fnames <- file.path('C:','Users','tbrown11','Desktop','indivs',
                    c( sprintf('indiv00.%i.csv', 1:4),
                       sprintf('indiv02.%i.csv', 1:3),
                       sprintf('indiv04.%i.csv', 1:6),
                       sprintf('indiv06.%i.csv', 1:5),
                       sprintf('indiv08.%i.csv', 1:9),
                       sprintf('indiv10.%i.csv', 1:5),
                       sprintf('indiv%i.csv',c(96,98)),
                       'indiv96.2.csv',
                       sprintf('indiv98.%i.csv', 2:3),
                       sprintf('indivs%i.csv',c(90,92,94)) )
                   )
# make a data frame to hold results:
results <- NULL

# LOOP THROUGH FILES:
for ( csvfile in fnames ) {
    # read.csv:
    tbl <- read.csv(csvfile)

    # do SELECT * from 'table' where Orgname like ...
    # Combine into one query:    
    dat <- sqldf("SELECT Cycle,FECTransID,ContribID,Contrib,ConFirst,RecipID,
    Orgname,UltOrg,RealCode,Date,Amount,Street,City,State,Zip,
    RecipCode,Type,CmteID,OtherID,Gender,FecOccEmp
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Orgname like '%Wal-Mart Stores% '
    GROUP BY ContribID, Cycle")

    # store these results:
    results <- rbind(results, dat)         
}

# finished. now just write your XML table:
library(XML)
out_file <- file( file.path('C:','Users','tbrown11','Desktop','Data','Retail',
                            'Walmart.csv'), open='a' )
write.table(results, file=out_file, sep=',', dec='.', quote=FALSE,
            col.names=NA, row.names=T)
close(out_file)
```

See how all your repeating code has been condensed into the one for-loop? That's the idea.

You may need to tweak to make sure:

1. the (combined) query works
2. do you really want to `write.table` with no column names? How will another person, looking at your CSV file, know that the columns are actually "Cycle", "FECTransID", "ContribID", ... etc ?